# Spring Boot with Application authentication (403 Fobidden) CSRF token was null. Has your session expired?

Tags: javascript, html, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application with thymeleaf template and using HTML with AngularJS as my frontend with mysql as DATABASE and data is passed in JSON

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4">
<head>
    <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>   
    <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
</head>
```

My JS file which value gets posted to :

```
$scope.logincheck = function() {

var dataObj = {
        userId : $scope.userId,
        password : $scope.password
};

var res = $http.post('http://localhost:9393/company/login', dataObj);
```

and the corresponding controller which handles mysql authentication :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/company/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

not getting called if CSRF is enabled. Upon CSRF enabling, i got 403 error saying CSRF token null was found.

My webconfig.java :

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http 
            .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/", "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/hello").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/accessdenied")
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("password").roles("ADMIN")
    }

    private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() 
    { 
        HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository(); 
        repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
        return repository; 
    }

    public class CsrfHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
          @Override
          protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
              throws ServletException, IOException {
              System.out.println("Inside Webappconfig.java");
            CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
            if (csrf != null) {
              Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
              String token = csrf.getToken();
              if (cookie==null || token!=null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                cookie.setPath("/");
                response.addCookie(cookie);
              }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
          }
        }
```

Comment: What is your client? Just regular js client or jsp?

Comment: Java Code there is no jsp !

Comment: The confirm popup is coming from the browser, so there is client. What is the client? Simple html,js or some framework?

Comment: I am trying to access a Html file and there comes a confirm like popup for authentication !!

When i remove this the authentication is not coming so it must be from spring framework


<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code solved the problem. The last line with httpBasic() function removal did the trick. Thanks everyone.

```
.authorizeRequests()
.antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated()
          .and()
           //Add this line to remove Authentication through browser problem 
          .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

> With the above code i get a **confirm like dialog box**...

I guess it's the default browser rendering for **Http Basic**. Maybe disabling Http Basic explicitly helps:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
          http
              .httpBasic().disable()
          ...
}
```

Comment: There is no such function called .httpBasic() and i am unable to disable the authentication and redirect to the HTML page

Comment: Before first `authorizeRequests`, you can use `httpBasic` method.

Comment: Tried what you suggested with no luck !!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong. In case of just simple html once you want to access to page it is restricted and that why the browser popup.

I suggest to copy demo from here using some templating:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html

In case you don't want to do the next thing:

```
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .and()
    .httpBasic().disable();
```

Please explain what the page you are requesting. If the page is not found the browser sometimes can do this popup. You need to explaing more what you want to accomplish and what is the page itself, what is the request etc..

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had js files under app dir.  This dir threw 403

Adding the following code helped.

.antMatchers("/static/**", "/app/**").permitAll()